# HTTP_RequestをHTTP_Request2で書き換え

Tags: php

開発言語はPHPです。

PearのHTTP_Request2を使ってHttpリクエストを送信、Httpレスポンス受信して処理する処理を実装しています。

あるサービスと契約してAPIを利用して実装を行います
APIを利用するためのPHPサンプルコードの提供を受けています。
サンプルコードを元に実装してるのですがサンプルが古くHTTP_Requestで実装されてます。
HTTP_RequestからHTTP_Request2へ書き換えています。
概ねメソッド名が変わっているだけなので対応するメソッドに置き換えています。

ひとつだけ「addRawPostData」だけどう置き換えて良いのか分からないので質問しました。
サンプルコードでは

```
//POSTデータ生成
$postdata =
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF8\"?>" .
"<request id=\"xxxxxxxxxxx\">" .
"<user_id>" . $user_id . "</user_id>" .
"<user_name>" . $user_name . "</user_name>" .
</request>" .

$req = new HTTP_Request($url);
$req->addRawPostData($postdata);
```

となっています。
利用するAPIではHttpリクエストする時に、XML形式でデータ送るために上記のような実装になっています。
addRawPostDataをHTTP_Request2では何で置き換えれば良いでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします

Comment: 使ってないのでわかりませんが、[HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.request.php)の**Setting "raw" request body** のサンプルの通りでいいのでは？

Comment: [setBody()](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/docs/latest/HTTP_Request2/HTTP_Request2.html#methodsetBody) というのがあって、これに直接 XML 等を渡して POST したりします。

Comment: @BLUEPIXYさん、 @Shironeさん　ありがとうございます。
サンプルにもあるようにsetBody() でいいみたいですね。
明日早速これで実装してみて試してみます。

Comment: 解決したのであれば、ご自分で回答を書いて承認してください

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP_RequestのaddRawPostData()はHTTP_Request2のsetBody()で置き換えることが出来ました。